# AllenNLP - dataset_reader config for transformers

Tags: allennlp

I would like to use bert for tokenization and also indexing for a seq2seq model and this is how my config file looks like so far:

```
{
"dataset_reader": {
    "type": "seq2seq",
    "end_symbol": "[SEP]",
    "quoting": 3,
    "source_token_indexers": {
        "tokens": {
            "type": "pretrained_transformer",
            "model_name": "bert-base-german-cased"
        }
    },
    "source_tokenizer": {
        "type": "pretrained_transformer",
        "model_name": "bert-base-german-cased"
    },
    "start_symbol": "[CLS]",
    "target_token_indexers": {
        "tokens": {
            "namespace": "tokens"
        }
    },
    "target_tokenizer": {
        "type": "pretrained_transformer",
        "add_special_tokens": true,
        "model_name": "bert-base-german-cased"
    }
},
```

and later when I load the model and use `predictor.predict_json` to predict sentences, the output looks like this.

> 'predicted_tokens': ['[CLS]', 'Die', 'meisten', 'Universitäts',
> '##abs', '##ch', '##lüsse', 'sind', 'nicht', 'p', '##raxis',
> '##orient', '##iert', 'und', 'bereit', '##en', 'die', 'Studenten',
> 'nicht', 'auf', 'die', 'wirklich', '##e', 'Welt', 'vor', '.', '[SEP]',
> '[SEP]', '[SEP]', '[SEP]', '[SEP]', '[SEP]', '[SEP]', '[SEP]',
> '[SEP]', '[SEP]', '[SEP]', '[SEP]', '[SEP]', '[SEP]']

I have 2 questions:

1. is this a normal output (considering all the '[SEP]' tokens in the end)? or am I doing something wrong in the config file?
2. is there any function that would convert these tokens to a human-readable sentence?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Please set `add_special_tokens = False`.
2. Use `tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_string` (which takes the list of subword tokens as input), where `tokenizer` refers to the tokenizer used by your DatasetReader.

Please let us know if you have further questions!

Comment: @arjuns...another followup:
 I'm getting an error when using the make_output_human_readable function:

`prediction_data = predictor.predict_json({"source": source})
sent = predictor._model.make_output_human_readable(prediction_data)`

I get the following error:

File "/python3.7/site-packages/allennlp_models/generation/modules/seq_decoders/auto_regressive.py", line 459, in indices_to_tokens batch_indeces = batch_indeces.detach().cpu().numpy() AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'detach'

Comment: This is because `predict_json` already calls `make_output_human_readable` internally. My apologies, I didn't read your question carefully. Let me ask a few folks, and I will get back to you.

Comment: @Droplet Let me know if this works for you: 

`tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_string(['[CLS]', 'Die', 'meisten', 'Universitäts', '##abs', '##ch', '##lüsse', 'sind', 'nicht', 'p', '##raxis', '##orient', '##iert', 'und', 'bereit', '##en', 'die', 'Studenten', 'nicht', 'auf', 'die', 'wirklich', '##e', 'Welt', 'vor', '.', '[SEP]', '[SEP]', '[SEP]', '[SEP]', '[SEP]', '[SEP]', '[SEP]', '[SEP]', '[SEP]', '[SEP]', '[SEP]', '[SEP]', '[SEP]', '[SEP]'])`

Comment: `tokenizer` refers to the tokenizer used by your DatasetReader. Additionally, please set `add_special_tokens = False`.

Comment: Thanks, @arjnus !
So here is what I did: `predictor._dataset_reader._target_tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_string(toks)`
however, I get this error:
_AttributeError: 'PretrainedTransformerTokenizer' object has no attribute 'convert_tokens_to_string'_

Comment: The `tokenizer` we want to use is the attribute of `_dataset_reader._target_tokenizer`, try:  `predictor._dataset_reader._target_tokenizer.tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_string(toks)`

Comment: @arjnus I sometimes get such outputs:
`['Universitäts', '##abs', '##ch', '##lüsse', 'sind', 'nicht', 'p', '##raxis', '##orient', '##iert', 'und', 'bereit', '##en', 'die', 'Studenten', 'nicht', 'auf', 'die', 'wirklich', '##e', 'Welt', 'vor', '.', '[SEP]', '[SEP]', '[SEP]', '.', '[SEP]', '[SEP]', '[SEP]', '.', '[SEP]', '[SEP]', '[SEP]', '.', '[SEP]', '[SEP]', 'auf', 'die', 'Studenten', 'nicht', 'auf', 'die', 'wirklich', '##e', 'Welt', 'vor', '.', '[SEP]', 'vor', '.', '[SEP]', '[SEP]']`
Could it be because of `add_special_tokens =False`?
There are tokens after [SEP].I'm not sure how to process

Comment: All `add_special_tokens` does is indicate if a `[CLS]` and `[SEP]` token should be prepended and appended, respectively, to the list of tokens. This is important for input sequences, but not for output sequences, especially if you intend them to be human-readable. I'm unsure what your task is; depending on your constraints, you may be able to just disregard everything after the period '.' Look at the [HuggingFace tokenization utils documentation](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/tokenizer.html#transformers.PreTrainedTokenizer.get_special_tokens_mask) for other helpfulfunctions.